# Convert characters to Chinese/Japanese characters from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2005, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having an issue where I am pulling some names from a SQL Server 2005 Database and trying to use values from an outputted CSV to create folders in a Windows directory using VBA in Excel but Chinese/Japanese characters are not appearing correctly.

In SQL Server the string is stored as

> ¡è‚¡ä»½æ

Instead of

> 股份

I'd like to be able fix the encoding of the string and use the corrected characters to name a new folder. I've determined that the issue is with the encoding and I can use the online [Recode](http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php) tool to convert portions of my file. However, I have not been able to find a way to convert the whole document which contains a mix of western characters and eastern characters. My options are:

1. Get SQL Server to output the characters
2. Convert the CSV file so that the characters are understood (possibly through iconv but haven't been successful yet)
3. Use VBA to convert the characters

My main difficulty is that I don't understand the encoding of these characters. I've read up on encoding from the article *[What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)* but I'm still trying to understand what is going on with my specific situation. I've also looked at [Unicode Support in SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962(v=sql.90).aspx#intlftrql2005_topic2) but haven't gotten the `Convert()` function to work.

#### Update

I tried converting from all the encodings available in [win-iconv](https://code.google.com/p/win-iconv/) into UTF-8 but was unable to get any usable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the East Asian characters were taken as binary and decoded as [extended ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/). One way to decode it is to:

1. Copy the broken text
2. Open Notepad++
3. Start a new file
4. Set the encoding to `Encode in ASCII`
5. Paste the text into the new file
6. Set the encoding to `Encode in UTF-8`

**Note:**
If there are any characters in the extended ASCII code table (128-255) such as an ñ, these may not be encoded correctly. Also, if the strings were truncated, there may be partial supplementary characters at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ADODB Stream object to open as text (for windows automatic conversions) or as binary (if you want the raw bytes unconverted).

1st make sure your locale, default language for non unicode programs, etc are set on both computers. Regional Options in Control Panel.

If no luck there try passing a ADODB binary stream (maybe as an array of bytes) to VBA's `StrConv` function. There's Win32 API functions with more control as well.

File.ResponseBody contains binary data from from XMLHTTP.

```
Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\safetyscanner.exe", 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've been unsuccessful when using the ADODB stream. The output is either the exact same or is unreadable.

Comment: What makes you think it's UTF - 8?

Comment: I don't think it's UTF-8 but I'd like it to be something standard. SQL Server 2005 uses UTF-16 but doesn't support "Supplementary Characters" (see [International Features in SQL-Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962(v=sql.90).aspx#intlftrql2005_topic2)).